# how to update new row in android sqlite database

Tags: android, mysql, database, sqlite, sql-update

Can anybody guide me.
I have an android app. That takes daily user entered value. I want that till same date on same day a user can enter n re-enter values in database , open or close app what ever but value just get updated till same date say for today 22/10/2014.

Now I have once inserted date value in my sqlite database. but if i just update it by user entered value so only one row is created n get updated, even if the date get change the next day.

But if I insert the date again then next row is created that I want actually. 
My problem is that : now how to update my sqlite database at most recent date.
My update of user value from a checkbox is going through this method.

```
public long send(boolean a) {
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();

        cv.put(SEND_Today, a);

    return ourDatabase.update(MY_DAILYTABLE, cv, DATE + "=" + "date", null);
```

it update all the rows as every row contain date column.
I want somthing like this

```
ourDatabase.update(My_DAILYTABLE , cv , "(select MAX(date) from My_DAILYTABLE )" , null;
     update dailydata set daily = 10 where date = (select max(date) from dailydata) // because I know sqlite run this query successfuly
```

But whatever query I write I get error.
Can anybody guide me a correct query to achieve this functionality. Just need to know the write update query in Android SQLite.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to give the entire WHERE clause, that is, also the `date =`:

```
ourDatabase.update(My_DAILYTABLE, cv, DATE+" = (select...)", null);
```

Answer (score 0):

**you can follow this:**

```
db.update(DB_TABLE, contentValues, DB_TABLE_ROW_NAME + " = ? ", new String[] { WHERE_DB_TABLE_ROW_VALUE });
```

**should:**

```
ourDatabase.update(MY_DAILYTABLE, cv, DATE + " =? " , new String[] { yourMaxDate });
```

**Or use rawQuery:**

```
String sql = "update dailydata set daily = 10 where date = (select max(date) from dailydata)";
Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(sql, null);
if (cursor2.moveToFirst()) {
    // can get column value as select query
}
```

Comment: let me try doing this way

Comment: Kindly check my first method in my question where I am getting a boolean value boolean a(this value is going to insert 1 if true else 0) I want to store this boolean value in my database in the column where date = max(date) so that it should be saved on the very updated daily date. I have also tried the way you have just defined in edited answer. It wont take user value. and if you give the querry somthing like string sql = "update..." + a + "where date = .." it wont work.

Comment: you can try to use 1 and 0 instead of true and false.

Comment: Sir #Md. Shahadat Sarker this is not my query that i should use 0 or 1 or other value. becuase I have checkboxes , if isChecked so a boolean gets true n store in this table otherwise unchecked checkbox gives 0 and update other database. But whatever the value is, i just want user entered value to get and store and update my database. and I am just asking simple sqlite UPDATE query in connection with ANDROID.